# Key value not being retrieved using CRegKey::QueryStringValue

Tags: mfc, registry

I am unable to retrieve string value from registry using CRegKey::QueryStringValue()
Here is my code please let me know where am going worng.Here is the code.

```
bool bResult;
int nSize = 50;
LPTSTR csKeyValue = NULL;
bResult = m_cKey.QueryStringValue(_T(REGISTRY_VALUE_NAME),csKeyValue,(ULONG*)&nSize);
if(bResult == ERROR_SUCCESS){

    return true;
}
```

Somebody please help me and point me to right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The return value of QueryStringValue is a LONG! Not a bool. Comapring a bool to ERROR_SUCCESS doen't make sense.What is returned? The value is the error code from the system...

Answer (score 1):

csKeyValue must be a pointer to a buffer that will receive the string data. Yours is pointing to NULL, which will not work. Declare a buffer with an ample size, such as wchar_t KeyValue[1024] and pass KeyValue.

Comment: It's worth noting that using [`RegQueryValueEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911.aspx) is no more trouble to use, and allows to query the required buffer size.